# Using IP wecam for live streaming in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

When I run this program it uses front camera of my Android phone. But I want to have video processing from back camera. How should i do it?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib



url = 'http://192.168.1.183:8080/shot.jpg'

while True:
    imgResp = urllib.urlopen(url)
    img = np.array(bytearray(imgResp.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
    img1 = cv2.imdecode(img, -1)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_red = np.array([30,150,50])
    upper_red = np.array([255,255,180])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(img1, img1, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow('img',res)
    cv2.waitKey(10)
```

Comment: did you try using the VideoCapture with cap(0) or cap(1) ?

Comment: I am using my phone as webcam... There is nothing like cap(0) or (1) option for me

Comment: How are you making your camera to show the current image at `'http://192.168.1.183:8080/shot.jpg'`? most probably that is the code you need to change, which you do not show or say.

Comment: I am using an app... Called IP webcam... It works on a local network... It shows my phones video stream... On that address....

Comment: ahhh, I think you have to enter first at 'http://192.168.1.183:8080/' and look for the option change back to front, or something like that. I used it only once.

Comment: I tried it... It is working in browser... But when i run code... It uses only front camera... Not the other one...

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib



url = 'http://192.168.1.183:8080/video'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
while True:
    _, img1 = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_red = np.array([30,150,50])
    upper_red = np.array([255,255,180])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(img1, img1, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow('img',res)
    cv2.waitKey(10)
```

I had passed the url into VideoCapture(). Then read the frames. It worked.

Added Code:

```
url = 'http://192.168.1.183:8080/video'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
(Inside while loop)
_, img1 = cap.read()
```